# Array is showing empty initially, and I believe it's causing ".map is not a function" error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I am attempting to fetch some data from a strapi api and I'm running into an issue where it's stating that .map is not a function of badgeCategories.

Here is a sample of the code which fetches the API and updates badgeCategories.

```
    export default function Home({ posts }) {

    const [badgeCategories, setbadgeCategories] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBadgeCatData = async () => {
      const badgeCatResult = await api.getBadgeCategories();

      setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data);
     };
    fetchBadgeCatData();
    }, [])
```

I attempted to console log badgeCategories and noticed that the array is initially empty on first run.

```
    {console.log(badgeCategories)}
```

[image: image of console log]

When the code gets to

```
     {badgeCategories.map((g) => (
            <div>
```

I get an error thrown stating

> TypeError: badgeCategories.map is not a function

My assumption is that the error is being thrown because the array is initially showing as empty so it cannot process the .map function; however I'm kind of stuck and have not been able to resolve this yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Full Map Body:

```
{badgeCategories.map((g) => (
            <div>
              <div className="pt-6 pb-4">
                <h1 className="text-2xl font-extrabold leading-4 tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10 md:text-2xl md:leading-9">
                  {g.attributes}
                </h1>
                <p className="text-md text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                  {g.description}
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="flex flex-wrap">
                  <ul className="w-full space-y-2">
                  
                  {itemData.filter(item => item.group == g.id).map(filteredItem => (
                    <li key={filteredItem.order}>
                    <Item
                      type={filteredItem.type}
                      text={filteredItem.text}
                      color={filteredItem.color}
                      href={filteredItem.href}
                      hrefActive={filteredItem.hrefActive}
                      />
                    </li> 
                  ))}
                  </ul>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: how about with `setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data.data);`

Comment: The title and hypothesis is incorrect. `[].map` is still valid; for *any array*, empty or not. However, `({}).map` (no array involved) could result in the error.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo - When I utilize setBadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data.data); i get the following error message stating that I should use an array.

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {displayName, createdAt, updatedAt, publishedAt, locale, description, order, identifier}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @dotmiikee could you include your map body

Comment: @SaeedShamloo, I have included the full body where I'm performing the .map.

Comment: I think `g.attributes` or `g.description` is object, right?

Comment: Before implementing the Strapi call to fetch this data I was utilizing a local array. I was going to address these once I can figure out the mapping error.

Comment: You mean your problem solved?

Comment: No, fetching the data from an API is not working.

Comment: but in the above picture, data is an array with two items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the array is empty initially. However, this should not throw an error as you set an initial value for the array in your `useState` call:

```javascript
const [badgeCategories, setbadgeCategories] = useState([]);
//                                            here     ^^
```

What could be causing an issue is actually not when the data has not loaded but when the data *already has loaded*. Based on the screenshot of your console, it seems that the new data is not an array.

```javascript
[] // before the data loads, `badgeCategories` is an empty array.
{ data: Array(2), meta: {...} } // after it loads, `badgeCategories` is an object 
                                // containing a `data` property of an array.
```

This seems to be coming from this line of code:

```javascript
const badgeCatResult = await api.getBadgeCategories();
setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data); // NOT an array!
```

It seems that `badgeCatResult.data` is not an array, but an object containing a `data` property that is an array. Try using this instead:

```javascript
const badgeCatResult = await api.getBadgeCategories();
setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data.data); // This should work!
```

Comment: Jacob, that makes a lot of sense however I have tried utilizing:

`const badgeCatResult = await api.getBadgeCategories();
setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data.data);`

it resulted in the following error message:

`Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {displayName, createdAt, updatedAt, publishedAt, locale, description, order, identifier}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @dotmiikee It seems like this worked but your structure within the `.map()` call is invalid because `g.attributes` or `g.description` is an object rather than a string. Try `console.log(badgeCatResult)` for debugging or use `JSON.stringify(g.attributes)` in the map body (and likewise for `g.description`)

Comment: Thank you @Jacob and @ Saeed Shamloo, I see what you are saying now and realize I missed what you both were saying. Utilizing `setbadgeCategories(badgeCatResult.data.data);` is the correct approach as the Strapi data structure changed from v3 to v4. Then I tested with utilizing `{g.attributes.displayName}` and this worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply avoid the error by checking badgeCategories is a valid Array before calling map

```
{Array.isArray(badgeCategories) && badgeCategories.map((g) => (
            <div>
    .....
    )
  }
```